# How to generate and execute code in twig?

Tags: twig

I've created a macro like this:

```
{% macro _path(my_path, param, js_var) %}
{% spaceless %}
    path('{{ my_path }}', { '{{ param }}': "%s" }) | url_decode | format('"+{{ js_var }}+"') | raw
{% endspaceless %}
{% endmacro %}
```

When I call it like this:

```
window.location ="{{ js.path('hqf_pizzas_searchpage', 'cp', 'monCP') }}";
```

It works, but it generates this:

```
window.location ="path('hqf_pizzas_searchpage', { 'cp': "%s" }) | url_decode | format('"+monCP+"') | raw";
```

Which is not what I want. I would just like Twig to execute, after the macro, the result to obtain this:

```
window.location ="/my-url/cp/"+monCP+"";
```

Any idea how yo could do this?

Comment: just change the content of the macro to `"/my-url/{{ param }}/" + {{ js_var }} + ""`?

Comment: Thank you, for your comment, but the point is that I dont want the URL to be hard-coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your macro body to this:

```
{{ path(my_path, { param: "+"~js_var~"+" }) }}
```

I'm not sure if the value of `param` will be passed correctly. If not, try this:

```
{% set params = {} %}
{% set params[param] = "+" ~ js_var ~ "+" %}
{{ path(my_path, params) }}
```